# Base path and user picture uploading

Tags: 7, media, uri

So I recently migrated my site between servers. I think this is causing some issue with the base path of Drupal, which in turn affects the image upload path when a user tries to upload an image to his/her profile.

So, before migrating, some data was already uploaded to some of the users and their images and paths work just fine. The path is as follows for example:

```
www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-125-1377507580.jpg
```

But now, when I'm trying to add new users and when I upload new pictures, the image doesn't get uploaded and the path to the image is as follows:

```
www.example.com/new/?q=sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-125-1377507580.jpg
```

Why is this happening? How do I change the Drupal base path? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your code how you are saving image?

Comment: I didn't manually write the code for saving the images. Images are saved directly by Drupal.

Comment: Whether or not this solves the problem, you can change the $base_url in sites/default/settings.php

Comment: You just need to enable clean urls from admin (admin/config/search/clean-urls). Just check mod_rewrite is enabled on sever

Comment: Are you sure you copied the `.htaccess` file as well?

Comment: Enable clean URL. This issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems that the **new server does not allow clean urls** or it needs some configuration. Check the documentation on Drupal.org: [Step 6: Configure clean URLs](https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls)

Then, clean all caches and run cron. You will then see all image paths as /new/sites/sites/default/files/...

That's because the new site is set on folder ROOT/new or am I wrong? So there is no error, you have to **set the domain to look at this subfolder**.

If you don't have permissions to do this in your hosting or there are no options like Add-On domains you can follow the discussion at [**Drupal installed in subdirectory but made to appear in root**](https://drupal.org/node/144643) according to your hosting enviiroment.

Comment: Alright, so I don't have clean URL's enabled. But that shouldn't be an issue right? I mean I don't want cleanURLS enabled anyway.

Comment: NO it is not an issue. Is the new site under ROOT/new folder?

Comment: Yes you are right. It's under ROOT/new

Comment: I 've edited my answer. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

First of all mention `$base_url = 'http://example.com';` in settings.php file. Then provide permission to your files folder. It should be at sites/default/files

Provide permissions:

```
cd /var/www/drupal_root/sites/default/
sudo chmod 777 -R files
```

Hope this helps